# Multiple choices to log into Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Currently I have users set up to connect to a Windows Server 2008 R2. I have noticed over the past few months some users have had issues remembering what user name is used where, so is there a way I can have a choice of multiple logins? For example:

A user, called Test User, can log in using either test.user or test.user@site.com??

If so, where do I enter this at??

Thanks!

Comment: Users logging on with domain accounts at the console or RDP logon prompt should be able to use any of the following: <username> to log on to the default domain, <PRE2K DOMAIN>\<username> to log on to the domain specified by a pre-Windows 2000 domain name, or <username>@<domain.com> to log on to the domain specified by the Windows 2000 domain name. For example, if the server is a member of the WILCOX domain aka wilcox.com, and my username is todd, then I could logon as "todd", "WILCOX\todd" or "todd@wilcox.com". They all refer to the same domain account.

Comment: Ah gotcha...we have a .local to login..but we have Google connected up so we use AD and Google Apps Directory Sync (GADS) to link accounts..notice a lot more people trying to use their email (.com) to try and connect up to the computers, and not their <username>, so we would have to specify in the server to use .com as a drop down choice instead of .local..